# Colors in neovim statusline only update after keypress

Tags: neovim, statusline

I use neovim and I made my own statusline, which used to work perfectly. It showed the status of the file (saved/modified etc) and the mode, in text as well as in color. The color got updated immediately (so when when a file got modified, and u was pressed, the file part of the statusline turned green again and it said "saved"). Since a recent update, this does not work anymore. The text still changes, but the color only updates after pressing another key.

Here is my code:

```
" Status and command line
function! GetModify()
    if &readonly || !&modifiable
        highlight User5 ctermfg=1 ctermbg=none cterm=bold
        highlight User6 ctermfg=0 ctermbg=1 cterm=bold
        redraw
        return '(Readonly)'
    elseif &modified
        highlight User5 ctermfg=9 ctermbg=none cterm=bold
        highlight User6 ctermfg=0 ctermbg=9 cterm=bold
        redraw
        return '(Modefied)'
    elseif empty(glob(expand('%:p')))
        highlight User5 ctermfg=12 ctermbg=none cterm=bold
        highlight User6 ctermfg=0 ctermbg=12 cterm=bold
        redraw
        return '(New)     '
    else
        highlight User5 ctermfg=10 ctermbg=none cterm=bold
        highlight User6 ctermfg=0 ctermbg=10 cterm=bold
        redraw
        return '(Saved)   '
    endif
endfunction
function! GetMode()
    let mode=mode()
    if mode=='n'
        highlight User2 ctermfg=0 ctermbg=11 cterm=bold
        highlight User3 ctermfg=11 cterm=bold
        redraw
        return 'Normal '
    elseif mode=='i'
        highlight User2 ctermfg=0 ctermbg=2 cterm=bold
        highlight User3 ctermfg=2 cterm=bold
        redraw
        return 'Insert '
    elseif mode=='c'
        highlight User2 ctermfg=0 ctermbg=14 cterm=bold
        highlight User3 ctermfg=14 cterm=bold
        redraw
        return 'Command'
    elseif mode=='v'||mode==''
        highlight User2 ctermfg=0 ctermbg=12 cterm=bold
        highlight User3 ctermfg=12 cterm=bold
        redraw
        return 'Visual '
    elseif mode=='R'
        highlight User2 ctermfg=0 ctermbg=1 cterm=bold
        highlight User3 ctermfg=1 cterm=bold
        redraw
        return 'Replace'
    else
        return mode
    endif
endfunction
function! GetRecording()
    highlight statusline ctermfg=15 ctermbg=0
    highlight User1 ctermfg=7 ctermbg=5 cterm=bold
    highlight User4 ctermfg=15
    redraw
    if reg_recording()!=''
        return '  Recording @'.reg_recording().' '
    else
        return ''
    endif
endfunction
function! GetPath()
    let length=winwidth('%')-44-3
    if reg_recording()!=''
        let length-=14
    endif
    let path=substitute(expand('%:p'),'^'.expand('~'),'~','')
    if len(path)>length
        return '...'.path[-length:]
    else
        return path
    endif
endfunction
set statusline=
set statusline+=%1*%{GetRecording()}
set statusline+=%2*\ %{GetMode()}\ %3*
set statusline+=%4*%4(%c%),%3(%l%)/%L\ [%4(%p%)%%]
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=\ %5*%6*\ %{GetPath()}
set statusline+=\ %{GetModify()}
set laststatus=2
set showcmd
set noshowmode
```

The code is not very nice or exhaustive, but it used to work. I tested it with an empty init.vim file (only a reference to this file), but that had the same problem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use neovim issue tracker.